# Can I remove a GSM module from an old cell phone?

Tags: wireless, gsm

I found this [project that uses a GSM module](http://www.serasidis.gr/circuits/SMSremoteV3/SMSrcV3.htm) (scroll down to see Picture 5). It seems the module has to be bought separately. I have old GSM cell phones lying around in the house. Shouldn't these phones contain such a chip? Is it possible to remove the chip and use it on a circuit board as shown in some of the pictures in the project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does connection cables exist for your phone? Or, if it is a Nokia, are there pins behind the battery?

If yes, your old phone is probably able to receive **AT** or **FBUS** command, allowing you to easily use the internal modem, for example to send/receive sms.

Look at [this page](http://www.embedtronics.com/nokia/fbus.html) for information about the **FBUS** protocol (for Nokias).
[This other page](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Using_AT_commands_to_send_and_read_SMS) deals with **AT** commands to send an read SMS (This should work with most phones).

Search about this (for example on chiphacker), many people have done such things.

There also exists standalone **GSM** modules ([example at SparkFun](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product%5Finfo.php?products%5Fid=9533)).

Comment: I hadn't thought of trying to use the phone as a whole unit. Good idea!

Comment: So, good luck in your tests :)

Comment: Yes, my Nokia phone has those pins behind the battery. Thanks for the links!

Comment: @mehdi please don't make trivial edits to ten year old posts.  Contrary to the false claim in your edit message, you didn't "correct" anything but just randomly and inappropriately bolded some words

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, no.

In cell phones, the RF components are very tightly integrated with everything else.
Basically, for size and cost reasons, they design a custom circuit board with the GSM interface devices and the actual phone hardware all assembled together.

It may be possible to tap the interface between whatever local processor the phone uses, and the RF stage, but it would very likely not provide a simple interface similar to the module used on the linked page. In any event, it would be a **significant** challenge to even get access to the interface wiring, as most phones use PCBs with many layers (4-10), and all the parts are generally BGA.
In addition to this, you would also likely have to do a lot of processing to get the RF section of the phone to properly communicate with the cell towers, since it's likely that the phones main processor handles some portion of the wireless interface protocol. This would require a fairly powerful MCU and non-trivial programming effort.

Basically, there is a reason they sell phone modules like that.

---

@Klaus's idea about using the phone as a whole is a much better idea. No PCB hacking there.

If some nokia's have a built-in AT command interface, and you have one of those phones, you should be good to go. Effectively, the *whole phone* is one of those GSM modules.